# Should we do anything for answers on duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65728/11262) was added during a close-as-duplicate vote. There's some discussion of the answer in the comments; some of that is just how we typically receive the idea central to the answer here, but **some of it is about how to improve the answer**.

It seems like there's tension between improving that answer and the idea of closing the question in the first place--which, as far I know, is to direct any additional answers back to one question and centralize them more.

Should we encourage that answer, and future answers in a similar situation, to be moved to one of the other questions it's a duplicate of (unfortunately, that particular question has been asked and answered her over and over and over) if it's going to be worked on?  Or is it more appropriate to let answers that end up on closed questions stay where they are?

Comment: Somewhat related to the answer linked in the question since it was also on duplicate question that got closed https://space.stackexchange.com/a/64236/44505

Comment: This is a great question, and I'm going to need to think about it before answering.

Comment: In this case, I do not think the question was a duplicate. In the question that was referenced was about "horizontal launch" and seemed to me to be about the vehicle *powering itself*, but initially travelling horizontally as opposed to vertically - perhaps down a runway and then off a cliff (or wings?). Basically build up some horizontal speed *without* gravity losses during the initial part of the first stage burn. The new question was about placing a rocket on a high speed train. While different "why don't we" questions may have similar answers, I'm seeing a lot of variety in the answers.

Comment: Also, a critical assumption in the new question is that the rocket could be made a lot smaller. Which my question helped to quantify a bit.

Answer (score -3):

I'm always willing to improve an answer. I also feel that the comments from other people generally also improve the answer, even if the text of the answer doesn't get updated, because people will read the comments, consider them, and reach their own conclusions.

I'm not sure that moving an answer from one question to another will work. Without the correct context, it could be confusing. I could take a look at the earlier question to see if a similar answer might be helpful there too though.

I did notice one comment that I think helps to shed some light on an underlying problem. It said...

> This type of idea has been looked at for decades by rocket scientists but so far not found to be a better method.

I don't disagree with the accuracy of this statement, but I still think that there is a problem with it.

Let's suppose, for a moment, that we're living in the 1980's when everyone used incandescent light bulbs and drove ICE cars. Lots of alternative ideas were proposed and a statement like...

> This type of idea has been looked at for decades by incandescent bulb scientists but so far not found to be a better method.

... could have been made to a kid asking about why we don't just make a white LED,

Or...

> This type of idea has been looked at for decades by internal combustion engine scientists but so far not found to be a better method.

... could have be made to a young engineer asking why we don't just use electric motors to drive cars.

I think the people who come up with these ideas deserve bespoke answers to their questions. Moreover, the ideas they come up with should not be characterized as a being "a type of idea", and then closed-as-duplicate.

There's a pretty high probability that some of us who have been here for a while will see similarities between ideas expressed in old posts and ideas expressed in new posts. But this doesn't necessarily mean that he ideas and the questions are *the same*.

I think we should ask the OP if the answer(s) to an earlier question address(es) their question, and see how they respond before we consider closing the question as a duplicate.

In this case, I'm voting to reopen. I hope that the people who voted to close will take a closer look at the two questions and cast their votes to reopen as well.

Comment: this definitely isn't the place to debate whether or not that question was a duplicate. This meta-question applies more broadly to what site policy should be (hence, it being asked in meta, instead of the comments to that question)

Comment: The question states, "unfortunately, that particular question has been asked and answered her over and over and over" which puts the issue of whether the question was, in fact, a duplicate into play. However, this answer does not debate that point - but my comments on the question do.

Comment: The question of whether or not a question is a duplicate is not in play. It was resolved by vote, and our safeguard against that is being able to vote to re-open. Feel free to do that, and argue your reasoning there. In the context of this question, the question being a duplicate is a matter of fact, as decided by vote. It broadly applies to exactly the same class of question: where the community has decided they are duplicates. Your thinking every question should have a bespoke answer is in direct opposition to longstanding site and community policy and, as such, is a different issue.